# В python 3 не работает функция exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

Пишу для себя небольшую программку, столкнулся с проблемой: `exec('y=' + func)`, где `func` - строка, в итоге потом просто напросто пишу `print(y)` и мне выдаёт ошибку

> NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Возможно это происходит из-за того, что это всё происходит в функции.

Comment: Приведите [mcve], демонстирующий проблему, потому что у меня `func='5'; exec('y=' + func); print(y)` превосходно работает

Comment: В данном случае логичнее использовать `eval`: `y = eval(func)`

Comment: Во-первых, ваша ошибка не воспроизводится, всё прекрасно срабатывает. Во-вторых, ни exec, ни eval вообще никогда не стоит использовать. Если вам кажется, что без них не обойтись, то, скорее всего, вы что-то делаете не так. Например, что вам мешает написать просто y=func ?